# What are some of the implications of using a medium-format lens on a DSLR?

Tags: lens, dslr, medium-format

Medium format lenses can be used on DSLRs via tilt/shift-adapters (Mirex, Zoerk, etc.). 
A medium format lens with a focal length of, for example, 80mm, has as equivalent focal length on small format 50mm. When I use that MF-lens on a full frame DSLR, the focal length is unchanged, but due to the smaller sensor of the FF-DSLR it wouldn't be as much covered as with a medium format camera with 6x6 film/sensor. 
So if I put up a medium format camera and a FF-DSLR side by side, equipped both with the same medium format lens,

- would I get the same magnification and angle of view from both
- would I have to shift with the adapter on the DSLR to get the same result
- it won't be possible to get the same image section with the same magnification?

Answer (score 1):

```
would I get the same magnification and angle of view from both
```

No. Your 80mm lens will stay 80mm thus the angle of view is smaller on your 35mm full frame DSLR.

```
would I have to shift with the adapter on the DSLR to get the same result
```

No. You can shift but you don't have to.

```
it won't be possible to get the same image section with the same magnification?
```

I don't get that question, please reword it. If you want a 50mm experience on your DSLR you can pick a 50mm Medium Format lens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As far as I understood it, when I use a 80mm MF-Lens on a full-frame DSLR, I get a smaller angle of view compared to when the lens is used on a medium format camera, and is equivalent to a 80mm FX lens, with the exception that I can, via shifting, stitch together a bigger image because of the bigger image circle of the MF-lens. So, to rephrase my last question, could I, via stitching, approximate the image I would get with the MF-lens on a medium format camera?

Comment: @StefanFeiner Yes.

Comment: @StefanFeiner A tilt shift lens made for full frame cameras would also allow you to use shift to cover a wider area by stitching. One reason the T/S lenses are so expensive is that the image circle they project must be large enough to accommodate the shift movements.